# SQL Server: Alter procedure on linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to alter procedure/function on linked server?

I guess ALTER PROCEDURE [linked\server].[dbname].[dbo].[proc] won't work?

Comment: why you just dont try it?

Comment: The object name '' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

Answer (score 5):

Right, I managed to get it done myself.
The way to do this is quite simple:

```
EXEC [linked_server].[dbName].[dbo].sp_executesql N' ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ProcName .......';
```

The linked server has to be RPC Out.